# Can a CSS tooltip or popup handle the case where the tooltip is not visible inside the window?

Tags: css, tooltip

There may be 2 ways to do tooltips or pop-ups -- one is using JavaScript, and the other is using CSS.

The CSS method has some elegance to it, but what about the case of, if the tooltip will show below a link or button, and the tooltip will not be visible inside of the window? (because the user scrolled to such position). If using JavaScript, the tooltip can actually be shown above instead of below in such case.  Can CSS achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding CSS depending of the layout for you popup/tool-tip.

You could consider positioning your element with `position: fixed;`.

You element will be positioned relative to the view-port, this means it always stays in the same place even if the window is scrolled.

Regarding the stack order of an element you could use `CSS z-index Property`.

Comment: no, what I mean is, say, the window is 1000 x 780.  The link or button is at y-position 760, or 740, and the tooltip is designed to show some 20px, 30px below, and the tooltip is say, 80 x 60, so the tooltip won't be visible on screen. (and it is a trouble if the link is in a sticky bar, and that link is *always* near 760 of the window.  We can say, well, let's make it pop up above, instead of below.  But then what about the case of the link at y-position 20px?  Then the tooltip won't be on screen either.

Comment: I suppose in that case you should work a JS solutions. You could add a JSfiddle here with your markup I will have a look for a solution. Thanks!